# Validar array en condición Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente Array

```
Arreglo = [ "jose" ];
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es, que si en el arreglo esta "Jose" arroje un mensaje que si paso en fin.

tipo asi

```
if( Arreglo.indexOf( 'Jose' ) == 0){
   alert("puede pasar");
}
```

Al validar que si esta jose, pasa el alert sin prolema.

Ahora lo quiero hacer es que si en el arreglo esta así

```
Arreglo = [ "jose", "maria", "marta" ];
```

Es sacar un mesanje que diga que Jose no puede estar con Maria ni marta, pero si entre ellas.

Algo asi

```
if( Arreglo.indexOf( 'Jose' ) == 0 && Arreglo.indexOf( 'Maria' ) ){
   alert("Jose no puede pasar con maria");
}elseif(Arreglo.indexOf( 'jose' ) == 0 && Arreglo.indexOf( 'marta' )){
   alert("Jose no puede pasar con marta");
}

if( Arreglo.indexOf( 'marta' ) == 0 && Arreglo.indexOf( 'Maria' ) ){
   alert("pueden pasar");
}
```

Pero con los if solo le estoy diciendo si existen tales nombres.

Para aclarar Jose debe ir completamente solo, no puede pasar si hay otros nombres en el arreglo es decir asi ejemplo["jose","maria","etc"].
si el arreglo esta asi ["jose"], si puede pasar.

Que herramienta me serviría para lograrlo?

Comment: Resume tu pregunta a ver si entendí: José debe pasar solo SIEMPRE, no puede ir con nadie. Marta y María pueden pasar si van juntas ¿Pero y si van solas? Los requerimientos están como un poco difusos...

Comment: sin van solas también pasan. La validación es si José quiere entrar con alguna de las 2

Comment: no bastaría con saber si está jose, y que sepas que es el único elemento del array?

Comment: así podría evitar la combinación entre José y los otros? aunque como tal no te entendí.

Comment: José puede estar acompañado de alguien más que no sea María ni Marta? José solamente debe ir solo? José puede ir con Marta y alguien más o José puede ir con María y alguien más?

Comment: debe ir completamente solo, ya aclare mejor en la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces bastaría con que valides que José esté solo en el array y problema solucionado, en cualquier otro caso José no puede pasar.

Comment: lo que pasa es que no controlo lo que llegue en el array, error mío al no decirlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pienso que primero como mencionan debes validar si jose esta en el array para esto usariamos `includes` que nos ayuda a validar si un elemento se encuentra en el array o si no esta para que pueda pasar, el resto no podria pasar.

```js
function validatePeople(){
  const people = [ "jose", "maria" ];
  if((people.includes("jose") && people.length == 1) || !people.includes("jose")){
    return "Puedes pasar"
  }
  
  return "No puedes pasar"
}

console.log(validatePeople());
```

Comment: Me funciono tu respuesta, pero no la entendí muy bien lo que hace. "people.includes("jose") && people.length == 1) " aca se validad si jose esta en el arreglo pero aca !people.includes("jose") valida los que sean distintos?

Comment: Claro en la primera valida si jose esta en la lista y ademas esta solo el en la lista (["jose"]), o si no esta el (["maria", "marta"]), en esos casos indicas puede pasar, de lo contrario, no pasa.